# Error timed out python3

Tags: python-3.x

Cordial saludo.
En la actualidad estoy desarrollando un cliente webservice con python3. Cada que ejecuto el cliente, se deben cargar en una tabla de SQL SERVER unos 364 registros. Si el registro no tiene datos, no se carga en la base de datos.

Cuando lo ejecute por primera vez, funciono, pero al seguirlo ejecutando manualmente días posteriores, me empezó a salir el `ERROR: timed out`.

Noté que el error se produce cuando no hay registros, pero no se produce en el primer caso que se presente, sino en casos posteriores, inclusive al correr nuevamente el cliente, se detiene en un registro diferente mostrando que no es un registro en particular el que tiene el error.

Para ingresar la información, ejecuto un ciclo FOR, por lo que pensé que el servidor de donde me entregan el webservice, se bloqueaba por hacerle muchas peticiones. Con base en ello, le puse al ciclo FOR un `time.sleep(0.5)` en la parte donde no hay registros así:

```
contador = 0
    for matricula in equipos:
        contador+=1
        #mensaje que permite saber en linea de comandos, en que registro vamos y cuantos 
        #faltan
        print('Procesando maticula %i de %i'%(contador,nro_matriculas))
        datos = cosultarEquipoWs(matricula)
        if datos is None:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            continue
        else:
            InsertarDatos(datos)
            #print (datos)
    print('Finaliza')
    log('Finaliza ejecucion con exito')
except Exception as e:
    log('ERROR: '+str(e))
```

Como pueden notar, en el if, coloque el `time.sleep(0.5)`, el cual funciono bien en unos dias, pero luego volvió a presentar el ERROR: timed out, por lo que comencé a aumentarlo a `time.sleep(0.6)` y así sucesivamente sin lograr corregirlo.

Debido a que no he podido corregir el problema de raiz y teniendo presente que este cliente se debe ejecutar automáticamente y lo ideal es que no tenga este tipo de errores, solicito de su apoyo.

Comment: Yo pondría el sleep tanto si el dato es None como si no. De lo contrario la frecuencia de peticiones al servidor podría ser muy alta y hacer que se dispare alguna protección anti-DOS, que ignore las peticiones que vengan desde tu IP, lo que explicaría los timeouts que te da a partir de un cierto punto.

Comment: abulafia, gracias por la respuesta. Intente lo que me dijiste y comencé con ambos casos (none y no none) colocándoles un time.sleep(0.5), funciono bien una vez, pero al generar otro dia manualmente, volvió y salió el error timed out. La solución es jugar con el tiempo optimo del time.sleep e ir aumentándolo cada que falle? Agradezco me guíes por favor

Comment: Habría que saber por qué sucede ese timeout. No veo yo que sea buena estrategia dar palos de ciego aumentando los tiempos. ¿Cuántas peticiones calculas que puedas estar enviando por minuto a ese servidor (tanto las que fallan como las que no)? ¿Quién gestiona al servidor, es tuyo? ¿Tienes permiso para hacerle tantas peticiones? Yo sospecho que un alto ratio de peticiones o bien causa que salte algún sistema de protección anti DoS, o bien que directamente es demasiado elevado para el servidor y le hace "colapsar", pero es difícil diagnosticarlo sin más información.

Comment: @abulafia, procedo con las respuestas:  ¿Cuántas peticiones calculas que puedas estar enviando por minuto a ese servidor (tanto las que fallan como las que no)? 59 peticiones ¿Quién gestiona al servidor, es tuyo? no ¿Tienes permiso para hacerle tantas peticiones? me dieron el webservice, pero desconozco si tengo alguna limitante en las cantidad de peticiones al desarrollar el cliente.

Comment: Una vez que el webservice te ha dado un "timeout", ¿puedes acceder al mismo desde un navegador por ejemplo, o también te da timeout? ¿Y desde un navegador pero _desde otra red_ (por ejemplo, desde el celular)? Si el servidor no responde desde ninguna red, es que se ha caido. Si solo deja de responder a tu PC es que te han bloqueado. En cualquier caso parece que hay una limitación al número de peticiones por minuto. Intenta averiguar qué restricción tienes y entretanto tendrás que aumentar el tiempo de sleep. Una petición por segundo no debería causar problemas creo yo, pero en fin...

Comment: ok @abulafia, muy buenos consejos y te cuento que me han funcionado. Gracias.